# displayed value in functional component inside return

Tags: reactjs

i try to populate value from the object

My object

```
{ 
    "title": 5
    "value": 6
    "second": "2019-03-06" 
}
```

My render part . it showing error in both map as well as foreach

```
{newAttributes.forEach((data) => {
            <React.Fragment>
                 
                    <label > {data.title} </label>
                 
                    <label  >{data.value} -</label>
                 
                    <label  > {data.second} </label>
                 
            </React.Fragment>
             
             })}
```

in map i tried this
other than key i cant get other values

```
{Object.keys(newAttributes).map((key) => ( 

<React.Fragment>
                     
                        <label > {newAttributes.title} </label>
                     
                        <label  >{newAttributes.value} -</label>
                     
                        <label  > {newAttributes.second} </label>
                     
                </React.Fragment>
                 
                 ))}
```

Comment: if it's just a object (not array of object), do you need forEach? and if it's an array you should use a array.map() and you should return a value from it

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress :  question updated. map also i tried. it was not working

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed to return a value from map and the way you access properties

```
{
    Object.keys(newAttributes).map((data) => {
        return <label> {newAttributes[key]} </label>
   })
}
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zbybmb)

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the resulting array from `map` in a container element. in the code you posted, you would be returning an array of `React.Fragment`, instead of a single `React.Fragment` with the array of label elements as its children.

```
    <>
        {
            Object.keys(newAttributes).map((key) => {
                const label = newAttributes[key];
                return <label>{label}</label>;
            })
        }
    </>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation in your answer.